# ffmpeg padding doesn't scale when changing resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command which takes a bunch of audio files, 3 image files, and renders a video with them.

Image Input Dimmensions:

- 1_front.jpg 600w x 593h
- 2_back.jpg 600w x 466h
- 3_cd.jpg 600w x 598h

The video has a resolution of **w=600 h=593**, which is the resolution of the first img.

Here's the full command

```
ffmpeg
 -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\10. Deejay Punk-Roc - Knock 'em All The Way Out.aiff"
 -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\11. Deejay Punk-Roc - Spring Break.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\12. Deejay Punk-Roc - Fat Gold Chain.aiff" 
 -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\1_front.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\2_back.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\3_cd.jpg" 
 
 -filter_complex 
 "
 [0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]; 
 
 [3:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v3]; 

 [4:v]pad=600:593:0:63:color=pink,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];
 
 [5:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v5];
 
 [v3][v4][v5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]"
 
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 870.04 
  "E:\filepath\vidOutPutCorrect.mkv"
```

For filter_complex this second part will add padding to the second image so that it does not get stretched or cropped.

```
[4:v]pad=600:593:0:63:color=pink,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];
```

Specifically this part

```
pad=600:593:0:63:color=pink
```

Which I understand means w=600 and h=593, but i dont know that the last part `0:63` means.

You can see the output has the pink padding correctly
[image]

but i want to render the video with a resolution of w=1920 h=1898 instead of w=600 h=593.

So i update the command to have this new resolution:

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\10. Deejay Punk-Roc - Knock 'em All The Way Out.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\11. Deejay Punk-Roc - Spring Break.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\12. Deejay Punk-Roc - Fat Gold Chain.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\1_front.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\2_back.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\filepath\3_cd.jpg" 

-filter_complex "
[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];

[3:v]scale=w=1920:h=1898,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v3];

[4:v]pad=1920:1898:0:63:color=pink,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];

[5:v]scale=w=1920:h=1898,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v5];

[v3][v4][v5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]"

 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 870.04 "E:\filepath\slidet.mkv"
```

my video does in fact now have a resolution of 1920x1798 which is great, but the 2nd image padding portion has the image super small and in a corner

[image]

So this line works:

```
pad=600:593:0:63:color=pink
```

but with a different resolution is looks bad with the image in the top left corner

```
pad=1920:1898:0:63:color=pink
```

**What do I need to change `0:63` to in order to have the image be centered ?**

Download files: http://www.mediafire.com/folder/e8ja1n8elszk1lu,dxw4vglrz7polyh,ojjx6kcqruksv5r,lah9rano4svj46o,q5jg0083vbj9y1p,d3pt8ydf3ulqm5m/shared

Comment: use it by this way `...pad=1920:1898:-1:-1...` from docs: If x or y evaluate to a negative number, they’ll be changed so the input image is centered on the padded area.

Comment: the image is in fact centered in the area, but there is a bunch of black space surrounding the image. I think because the image dimensions are `600w x 466h`, but the video frame is `1920x1898`. So this line `[4:v]pad=1920:1898:-1:-1:color=black,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];` places the image centered within the frame, but extremely small

Comment: do you want to scale and pad? `...[4:v]scale=1920:1898:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=1920:1898:-1:-1...`

Comment: Thank you, this does correctly display the entire image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the filter_complex line for the second image (4th input file overall) to be

```
[4:v]scale=1920:1898:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1898:-1:-1,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];
```